# Reacstrap Form Reset input value MERN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, reactstrap

I started learning MERN stack, However, the issue is after i add new name and organisation base on my fields and reopen the modal, still the last value is on the form, how do i reset the form after reopening the modal? the thing is for adding new recipient you need to delete the previous add. it should be blank form input.... i don't want to install other dependencies and revise the code that is written.. thank you for answering.

```
 return (
<div>
  <Modal isOpen={modaladd} toggleAdd={toggleAdd} size="md" centered>
    <ModalHeader toggleAdd={toggleAdd}>
      <strong className="text-white">Add Recipient</strong>
    </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      <Form>
        <Label for="name">
          <small>
            <strong>Name</strong>
          </small>
        </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          id="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            return setRecipientFormData('name', newValue.target.value);
          }}
          required
        />
        <Label for="organisation">
          <small>
            <strong>Organization</strong>
          </small>
        </Label>
        <CreatableSelect
          classNamePrefix="select"
          value={{ label: organisation, value: organisation }}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            return setRecipientFormData('organisation', newValue.value);
          }}
          options={optionsOrgs}
        />
      </Form>
    </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
      <Button disabled={!isEnabled} color="primary" onClick={addRecipient}>
        Save
      </Button>{' '}
      <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggleAdd} >
        Cancel
      </Button>
    </ModalFooter>
  </Modal>
</div >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much code to work with, but probably in your `toggleAdd`(or whatever sets `modalAdd`) function you want to add:

```js
setRecipientFormData('name', "")
setRecipientFormData('organisation', "")
```